# included php code is not executing on submit

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm including a a php code with angular ui routing
the problem is if the millitary.php :

`

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Millitary Loot Table</h1>
    </div>
<?php
$MillitaryLoot = array( 
    'M4A4' => 47,
    'AWP' => 2,
    'Karambit' => 1,
    'Famas' => 50
    );
$newMillitaryLoot  = array();
foreach ($MillitaryLoot as $item=>$value)
{
    $newMillitaryLoot = array_merge($newMillitaryLoot, array_fill(0, $value, $item));
}
$myLoot = $newMillitaryLoot[array_rand($newMillitaryLoot)];
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "\n" . "<h2 style='display:inline;'>Item: </h2>" . '<p class="text-center text-danger">' . $myLoot . '</p>' . "</br>";
}
?>
        <form name="Gamble" action="" method="post" target="_self">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Gamble</button>
        </form>
        </br>
</div>
```

`

the include app.js

```
$stateProvider
        .state('millitary', {
            url: '/millitary',
            templateUrl: 'inc/millitary.php'
        })
```

is included into the index.php the submit button basicly not executes the code above the form

so basically i want the php code to execute in the index.php to keep the ui instead of jumping into the executing php file and losing the index.php linked styles and navigation

edit : if i run the code normaly it works but it doesn't if it gets included

edit2 : everything outside the if statement works basically if i add a echo "test"; it outputs but inside the if it does not so the problem is the form and the connection to the if statement

kind regards, daniel

Comment: what your expectation ?

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan probably echo the <h2>

Comment: I see nothing related to angularjs, nor its routing nor include, tags here stick to `php`

Comment: 'echo "\n" . "<h2 style='display:inline;'>Item: </h2>" . '<p class="text-center text-danger">' . $myLoot . '</p>' . "</br>";'

should be outputed but it doesn't execute

i added a preview via edit post

Comment: It will not execute that way. Okay, maybe its related to angular (you have added the preview). You should write a handler that posts this one, recieve response form another page and append it here, don't do it at one page, at last that's what people are trying to achieve with SPA's

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Gamble</button>
```

to

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Gamble" />
```

In order to submit you need a type `submit` `input` or use some client side script as javascript

Comment: thx for the comment didn't worked though
the code works fine standalone without include
but i need to include it to hold the styles and other content

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to the following:

```
<form id="form" name="Gamble" method="post">
     <button id="form" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Gamble</button>
</form>
```

You can submit your form with a button with HTML5 but it must share the same ID of the form. Also keep in mind this will only be supported with browsers that support HTML5 so if not they won't be able to submit the form.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

The other alternative is to use...

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Gamble">
```

as @gbestard suggested.

Comment: i changed it but it's still not working thx for the comment anyways

Comment: I have edited my answer, I believe you need to remove the action and use exactly as I provided. You may also need to remove `post`.

Comment: still no output after pressing submit

Comment: Does this page have a .php extension?

Comment: the index is a php (index.php) and the include is a php (millitary.php)

Comment: Inside your `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { }` condition, add a simple `echo "test";` to find out if your form is submitted. If you get output then the issue is with the `$myLoot` variable.

Comment: no output
but if i add a echo outside of the if statement it gets outputed so the problem has something to do with the form and the if statement i guess

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not getting submitted.